# Negative of a number in verilog using 2's complement

Tags: verilog

I have a number "A" that is 16 bit wide and is represented in 2's complement. How do I get "-A" in verilog?

Comment: Well, `-A`. Unsigned and two's complement negation are equivalent operations.

Comment: A could be negative or positive integer.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The unary minus operator yields the correct negated result, if it is representable as a two's complement result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wire [15:0] A;
wire [15:0] M_A; // Minus A

// The thing about 2's complement, is that the complement can be computed as NEG(x) + 1.
// In the following way:
assign M_A[15:0] = ~A[15:0] + 1'b1;
```

Comment: thankyou! I dint knew about the bit wise inversion using "~".

Answer (score 0):

```
reg [4:0] num;
reg  signed [4:0] neg;
 num= 5;   
$display("num= %5b", num);

neg= -num;  
$display("neg = %d", neg);
```

check this link : http://www.referencedesigner.com/tutorials/verilog/verilog_58.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2's complement of the stored 2's complement number to get -A.

Suppose here is the example.

```
- A = 10
  So in 2's complement A = 0000_0000_0000_0010
  Now for -A,
  2's complement of A = 1111_1111_1111_1110 (-10 in 2's complement form)

- A = -20
  So in 2's complement A = 1111_1111_1110_1100
  Now for -A,
  2's complement of A = 0000_0000_0001_0100 (20 in 2's complement form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I've done it in the past:

```
wire [7:0] A; 
wire [7:0] neg_A;

assign A = 8'd4;      //  4
assign neg_A = 0 - A; // -4
```

The compiler/synthesizer is smart enough to implement a 2's compliment operation in this case and the code is easily readable.